# Vue js attributes in xpage Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, xpages

Attributes not rendered when running xpage:
:Source code:

```
<div id="categories" class="article-search-results-categories">
<ul class="table-view">
<li class="table-view-cell  pr40" v-for="row in list.categories"> 
<xp:span id="clickSpan">{{row.name }}
<xp:this.attrs>
   <xp:attr name="v-on:click" value="alert('ok')" rendered="true" 
</xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
</xp:span>
</li>
</ul>


</div>
```

Script

```
var app = new Vue ({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      list:[]
   },
   methods:{
    getUsers: function(){
        var link = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        this.$http.get(link).then(function(response){
            this.list = response.data;
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });
    }, 

    getCategoryJSON: function(){

        var config  = {
                headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }

        var data = {
                "supplierid": "DAHL"
            };

        data = JSON.stringify(data);

        axios.post
('ProductViewJSONCtrl.xsp',data,config).then(function(response){
            app.list = response.data;

        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });


      },
     getLevel: function(row){
        console.log('clicked');
     }
  },
   mounted : function(){
        console.log("in mounted");
        this.getCategoryJSON();
   }
});
```

Output:

```
<span id="view:_id1:_id2:_id295:includeBody:_id328:clickSpan">VA- 
armatur/Stängventiler</span>
```

Any ideas why these attributes can't render?

The example with just the xpage tag  is correctly generated but the problem is when the spabn is in the v-for loop

Edited m surrounding codeas the problem is when VUE.js attahces and runs for loop

Comment: does the attr render with a different name ?

Comment: Yes . if i set a regular string as name and value it is rendered

Comment: There's a dot (.) at the end of 'rendered="true"'. If this is also present in your code then remove it and try again

Comment: Hi  Edited question as the output is OK if ran outside of v-for loop

Comment: Seems typo somwhere in roriginal code as now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```xml
<xp:span
    id="clickSpan">
    {{row.name }}
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr
            name="v-on:click"
            value="alert('ok')"
            rendered="true" />
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:span>
```

renders

```xml
<span id="view:_id1:clickSpan" v-on:click="alert('ok')">{{row.name }}</span>
```

So, it works.

I guess you have a syntax error in source panel and your changes don't take effect yet.

Comment: Sorrry edited ciode.  The code works when ran outside of the v-for loop

Comment: Seems to have beeen typo somwhere in code as now it works